# how to keep combination of cells unique

Tags: sql

i have table A and table B.  I have a bridge table called tableC

in table C i have:

```
ID
tableA_ID
tableB_ID
```

ID is the primary key.

i also want to enforce the combination of tableA_ID and tableB_ID to be unique so there are no duplicate records.

how do i enforce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create unique index myIdx on tableC(tableA_ID, tableB_ID)
```

or whatever the syntax for your particular  database system is.

Comment: This seems to be a many-to-many link table. In this case, `id` is usually redundant.

Comment: Very likely, but without knowing for sure, I just answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

Make the PRIMARY KEY tableA_ID and tableB_ID, EXCLUDING ID

lets say we have a table TABLEA with values

```
tableAID
1
2
3
```

and table TABLEB with values

```
tableBID
4
5
6
```

making the primary key (ID, tableA_ID, tableB_ID) will not work eg.

```
ID | tableAID | tableBID
1 | 1 | 4
2 | 1 | 4
```

will work fine with the above pk, but you need PRIMARY KEY (tableA_ID, tableB_ID)

Comment: He already has a primary key, I assume that can't be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the ID column then make the other two columns the primary key and their uniqueness will be enforced by the database server.
It's not really necessary to have the ID column - even though it serves as a handy way of referencing a particular record - as the uniqueness of the other two columns will mean that they are sufficient to reference a particular record.

You may also want to put an index on this table, that includes bothe columns, to make access faster.

Comment: If you make them PART of the primary key, the combinations will NOT be unique, the id can be used as a "history" or "order" but other than that it is useless

Comment: @astander - you're right about making them part of the primary key, and I should have known this (Good explanation in your answer). I usually don't include a surrogate key in join tables (and suggested that the ID was dropped), but will remember this in future.

Comment: @belugabob, correct the mistake and this answer can be UPvoted!

Comment: @Tony - My answer has been reworded, as you suggested, feel free to upvote (But I won't cry if you don't)